# Efficiently resize UITableViewCell on scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, real-time

**General Idea**

Im looking to resize UITableViewCells dynamically as the user scrolls the list, to say, make the items grow in size as they reach the bottom of the list.

**Considerations**

This is a process that needs to be refreshed multiple times per second as a call is made to:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

So it is impractical to take the `UITableView::ReloadData` approach so that a call is made to:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Since this will need to reload a bunch of extra data and slow down the system immensely.

**Needs**

- I will have at around 10 items on screen.
- entire list might have up to 100 items on extrem cases.
- Systems needs to scroll smoothly.
- Items need to expand and contract smoothly in real time as list scrolls.

**Common knowledge**

- This will definitely have some performance impact vs a list with static items.
- There are hundreds of threads dealing with the simple case of "resize cel to text length" which is not what I need, as that is a one time thing compared to this with lots of cycles per second.

**Possible approaches**

- Subclass `UITableView`.
- Have a static `UITableView` nested in a `UIScrollView`.
- Create an item list system from scratch and not use `UIScrollView` at all.

**Discarded approaches**

- Call `UITableView::ReloadData` per cycle so that `heightForRowAtIndexPath`: is called.

**So far**

I've already coded a module that calculates the math for item size.

**Conclusion**

I'm looking for the quickest way to solved this but I will recode my own `UITableView` if needed as a last resort.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @jacky boy, thanks for the edit and the observation. I deleted some questions that never got answered and keyed in some of the solutions I found. Most of my questions are answered now, except the two I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After heavy testing with `UITableView` I have not found a way to do this efficiently. It seems that `UITableView` might be optimized in a way that does not permit dynamic cell resizing. For this reason making a custom listing system seems to be the only option. I have begun work on such project building on top of `UIScrollView`.

A large part of the basic functionality is complete but the project is currently on hold as I have a more important system to develop as of present. If you are interested in taking part in this project let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath in the uitableview delegate data sheet.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

I had a similar problem that I needed to load the table cells first, then do something different to each cell on after the table was loaded or reloaded, might be what you're looking for.

Cheers

Comment: No, the problem is that you need to call UITableView::ReloadData to change the cell size. Since I'm resizing all the cells in real time as didScroll is called lots of calls to UITableView::ReloadData per second will have a massive performance hit.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah that wouldn't be the best solution then. Wish you luck though!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call -[UITableView reloadData] to update the geometry of cells. You can cause a UITableView to recalculate the geometry of cells by calling:

```
// force geometry update
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

This was mentioned in the [WWDC 2010 talk - Mastering Tableviews](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=128)

Comment: While this does work, from what I have tested, it still runs very slow if you call it in: `-(void) scrollViewDidScroll` so as to resize dynamicaly in realtime as the user scrolls. Have you managed to do this without a big performance hit @brian?